# Specify a xml catalog file to the maven 2 axis plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven, axis, maven-plugin

When I use the maven axis plugin to generate java code from a given wsdl file, it tries to reach out to the internet to resolve soap, wsdl etc schemas. Is there a way to specify the xml catalog file to the plugin or to maven in general?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the official Maven repository: [Plugin Repositories](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Repositories)

Or you could also add your own repository: [Using the Internal Repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)

Comment: I am not talking about dependencies